# Map scalars to arrays based on values : Image Processing 2D to 3D - NumPy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, rgba

Given a Numpy matrix of shape `(height, width)`, I am looking for the fastest way to create another Numpy matrix of shape `(height, width, 4)` where 4 represents `RGBA` values. I would like to do this value-based; so, for all values of 0 in the first matrix I would like to have a value of `[255, 255, 255, 0]` in the second matrix at the same location.

I would like to do this with NumPy without needing to slowly iterate like below:

```
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        if image[i][j] = 0:
            new_image[i][j] = [255, 255, 255, 0]
        elif image[i][j] = 1:
            new_image[i][j] = [0, 255, 0, 0.5]
```

As you can see, I am creating a matrix where the value 0 becomes transparent white, and 1 becomes green with an alpha of 0.5; are there faster NumPy solutions?

I am guessing `numpy.where` should greatly help speed up the process, but I haven't yet figured out the proper implementation for multiple and many value translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a cleaner solutiuon, especially when working with multiple *labels*, we could make use of [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html?highlight=searchsorted#numpy.searchsorted) to trace back the values for the mapping, like so -

```
# Edit to include more labels and values here            
label_ar = np.array([0,1]) # sorted label array
val_ar = np.array([[255, 255, 255, 0],[0, 255, 0, 0.5]])

# Get output array
out = val_ar[np.searchsorted(label_ar, image)]
```

Note that this assumes that all unique labels from `image` are in `label_ar`.

So, now let's say we have two more labels `2` and `3` in `image`, something like this -

```
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        if image[i,j] == 0:
            new_image[i,j] = [255, 255, 255, 0]
        elif image[i,j] == 1:
            new_image[i,j] = [0, 255, 0, 0.5]
        elif image[i,j] == 2:
            new_image[i,j] = [0, 255, 255, 0.5]
        elif image[i,j] == 3:
            new_image[i,j] = [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
```

We will edit the labels and values accordingly and use the same `searchsorted` solution -

```
label_ar = np.array([0,1,2,3]) # sorted label array
val_ar = np.array([
    [255, 255, 255, 0],
    [0, 255, 0, 0.5],
    [0, 255, 255, 0.5],
    [255, 255, 255, 0.5]])
```

Comment: Thank you, Divakar, for being so helpful. This is a fast solution and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are right `np.where` is how you solve this problem. Where is a vectorized function so it should be much faster than your solution.

I'm making an assumption here that there is It doesn't have an elif that I'm aware of, but you can get around that by nesting where statements.

```
 new_image = np.where(
           image == 0,
           [255, 255, 255, 0],
           np.where(
                image == 1,
                [0, 255, 0, 0.5],
                np.nan
           )
      )
```